# Decode base64 string in AWS AppSync Velocity resolver?

Tags: amazon-web-services, base64, graphql, velocity, aws-appsync

My aim is to create an AWS-AppSync GraphQL API that implements the [Relay Cursor Connections Specification](https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/connections.htm). Specifically I want to add [opaque cursors](https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/connections.htm#sec-Cursor) for some Elasticsearch queries. My cursor would be the sort values array for the search_after API. But to make them opaque I would like to stringify and base64 encode them before sending them to the client.

I know that AppSync exposes [base64 encode and decode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-util-reference.html) through its $util object. But decode returns a type of byte[] and not String. So my Question boils down to how to convert byte[] to String in Velocity?

Can we use the underlying Java for something like this:

```java
new String(bytes)
```

Unfortunately I don't know which classes are in the AppSync Velocity Context.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes)?